# Leiningen colours in Cygwin

Tags: clojure, cygwin, leiningen

I just got leiningen running perfectly in Cygwin using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634340/getting-leiningen-cygwin-working).  I frequently run tests like the good little dev I am, but I don't get coloured output in the console, which makes spotting the failures difficult sometimes.

Other commands in Cygwin are coloured correctly - how do I persuade leiningen (or midje, or clojure.test, or clojurescript.test) to colour its output in Cygwin?

Comment: [This answer from Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/469523/color-in-cygwin-terminal) may solve your problem.

Comment: So the problem I have is not getting colours to show in Cygwin - git uses loads, for example - it's getting the Clojure tools to do it.  They all output no colours at all.  I don't fully understand how colours are produced by processes writing to the terminal.

Comment: Does leiningen do colored output in other terminals? I've never seen that behavior before.

Comment: Well it manages fine in ConEmu at the moment, it's been a while since I ran it anywhere else but I always managed to have colours for `git` and `ls` when I used to use console 2

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a windows user so not sure about Cygwin but [aprint](https://github.com/razum2um/aprint) (Awesome Print) is a great leiningen plug-in.

[image]